# How to Resize a window so that all components are visible

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, intellij-idea, resize

First off I am using Intellij IDEA's GUI tool.
I have a window that has a browse button, if the user clicks the browse button they can explore their computer for an image file. If they choose an Image file then the window will add that image to the screen  next to the previous image, If the window just barely shows all the images and the user adds another one, I want the window to expand to be able to show the new image.

Does Java Swing have this capability? If so, how should I go about implementing it?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using appropriate layout managers, you can simple call `Window#pack`.

You should also consider checking out [How to use scroll panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html), cause I have some very large images...

The other thing you can look at is the [`Scrollable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Scrollable.html) interface

Comment: The program already has a scroll pane, but the images are resized automatically before they are put in the window.

Comment: An example would go a long way

Comment: I am using a Border Layout Manager, The only issue is that using Intellij's  Gui tool, I do not have a reference to the outermost Window to call pack on, is there a way to get a Window from a reference of a component on that Window?

Comment: [`SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#getWindowAncestor%28java.awt.Component%29)

Comment: Thanks MadProgrammer, SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor() was just what I needed